# Converting a map into a URI query string

Tags: elixir, reduce

I have an Elixir `Map`:

```
m1 = %{a: 1, b: "fsfd", c: 123}
```

I want to convert it into a query string for `URI`.

```
a=1&b=fsfd&c=123
```

How can I do that? I've tried this:

```
Enum.reduce(m1, fn({k, v}, acc) -> "#{acc}&{k}=#{v}" end)
```

But it didn't work, because the `acc` didn't get pattern matched as intended.

Comment: Any reason not to use `URI.encode_query/1`?

Answer (score 4):

You can use this:

```
URI.encode_query(%{a: 1, b: 2, c: "fdsfds"})
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is that you are using [`Enum.reduce/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#reduce/2) instead of [`Enum.reduce/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#reduce/3). Your passed function is executed `n - 1` times in `reduce/2`, with the first value used as the initial value of the `accumulator`.

So for your map, the initial value of accumulator would be `{:a, 1}`, a tuple which does not implement the `String.Chars` protocol. You can fix that by providing an initial accumulator value:

```
Enum.reduce(m1, "", fn({k, v}, acc) -> "#{acc}&{k}=#{v}" end)
```

---

### Elixir's in-built method:

As [@Dogbert pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42478509/converting-a-map-into-a-uri-query-string/42478593?noredirect=1#comment72097798_42478593), you can use [`URI.encode_query/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/URI.html#encode_query/1) instead of writing your own:

```
iex> URI.encode_query(%{foo: 1, bar: 2, baz: "value with spaces"})
"foo=1&bar=2&baz=value+with+spaces"
```

Comment: @Dogbert, I don't know :)

Comment: @Dogbert I feel stupid now, didn't know there was one built in (or just couldn't find it  :P). Updated the answer.

Comment: m1 = %{a: 1, b: "fsfd", c: 123} ; String.slice(Enum.reduce(m1, "", fn({k, v}, acc) -> "#{acc}#{k}=#{v}," end),0..-2)

Answer (score 1):

The OP's question has a simple example `map` with non-collections for values, so the `URI.encode_query(%{a: 1, b: 2})` answer is correct if you want to encode a `map` as per the URI standards.

However, `URI.encode_query/1` does not support maps which have list values and a lot of you will be using Phoenix and/or Plug and thus run with the convention that Plug enables of turning a query string like `a[]=1&a[]=2` into a list of values: `[1, 2]`. For you, there is:

```
iex(1)> Plug.Conn.Query.encode(%{a: [1, 2]})
"a[]=1&a[]=2"
```